# Posting quotes from the mobile app results in smart quotes

Tags: support, bug, ios-app

I was using the mobile app to post an answer just now and noticed that the single quotes I’d used in the query were coming out as smart quotes.

For example:

```
Select *
From   SomeTable
Where  Column = ‘value’
```

Or

```
string SomeVariable = “Some value.”;
```

Obviously, posting answers on the mobile app is a little more challenging, but it shouldn’t render the answers unusable without having to copy/paste and replace all of the quotes.

I’m not seeing any way of correcting the quotes without logging in to the main site, but that rather defeats the purpose of the mobile app.

- App version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 7 Plus
- OS version: Version 11.2 (Build 15C114)

Comment: As useful as this post could be for many users (definitely deserves upvotes), I don't believe this is on-topic for the meta site. This question is not asking anything related to / caused by Stack Overflow nor the software that powers Stack Overflow. Instead, this is a problem with the IOS 11 settings.

Comment: A similar feature request would be nice and on topic: "Automatically convert smart quotes to regular quotes when posting".

Comment: @abccd It [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44932863/371228) for iOS apps to override the system behavior and to prevent straight quotes from being converted to curly quotes. Given that information, I think this question describes a feature request rather than a bug but is on-topic.

Comment: @bdesham the feature request proposal should convert any curly quotes to straight quotes regardless if it's posted from the app, such as posting from the browser or just typing the curly quotes from a computer. Since curly quotes have absolutely no benefit when it comes to programming (all it does is cause syntax errors).

Comment: @abccd I kind of disagree: blindly converting all curly quotes to straight quotes would be very disruptive in the cases where users really do want curly quotes. (I use them all the time in the text parts of my questions and answers, and I use them freely inside string literals in code.) I do think we should make it harder for users to *accidentally* include curly quotes, but that doesn’t mean prohibiting them entirely.

Comment: Even with Smart Punctuation off, it's still possible to type smart quotes, just like it was before iOS 11. Just long-press the `"` key, and it will give you some other double quotes to choose from.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is an iOS 11 "feature" called [Smart Punctuation](https://www.macstories.net/stories/ios-11-the-macstories-review/10/#smart-punctuation). It might be useful for some folks, but not for programmers using Stack Overflow.

Fortunately, there's a way for you to disable it: go to the Settings app -> General -> Keyboards -> turn off the option "Smart Punctuation". According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44932863/4751173) (thanks @bdesham) it's possible to turn it off in the source code of the app, but this will take an update of the app, so it won't be live before [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/295232).

[image]

<sub>note: this post has been intentionally written without “smart” quotes.</sub>

Comment: `without “smart” quotes` ;)

Comment: _for just a single app_ ... too bad, because there is [a separate app for StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/154798/263422).

Comment: Is this new to iOS 11? I could have sworn it was around for much longer.